# Get an image from string Python

Tags: python, base64, png

I use a google API and now I want to get viewable png image from string, gained from API result.

```
screenshot": {
  "data": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU...VERY_LONG_STRING",
  "mimeType": "image/png"
 }
```

I have seen that I should use base64 lib, but It needs byte object, instead of string.
Finally I want to view that image manually, so I need to store it to disk.

How should I convert and save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base64.b64decode` works fine with both strings and bytes:

```
In [15]: import base64

In [16]: base64.b64decode('iVBORw0KGgoA')
Out[16]: b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00'

In [17]: base64.b64decode(b'iVBORw0KGgoA')
Out[17]: b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00'
```

Just write it to a file and view the image.